# "if(pointer) delete ponter" trys to delete even when pointer is not initialized

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, segmentation-fault

I wrote a very small *Observeable* implementation. When an observer is registered it deletes the old observer and instates the new observer.  However it tries to delete the pointer even if it has not been initialized. The code is as below:

Observable.h

```
class Observable
{
public:
    Observable();
    virtual void registerObserver(Observer * O);
    virtual ~Observable();

protected:
    Observer * myObserver;
};
```

Observable.cpp

```
#include "Observable.h"

Observable::Observable()
{
}


Observable::~Observable()
{
    if(myObserver)
        delete myObserver;
}

void Observable::registerObserver(Observer * O)
{
    if(myObserver)
        delete myObserver;
    myObserver=O;
}
```

all main does is

```
GUI * gui = new GUI();      // GUI extends Observer
Model * m = new Model();    //Model extends Observable
m->registerObserver(gui);   //I get a segfault inside this call
```

If I step through `registerObserver`, I see that even though I have never initialized `myObserver`, the statement *if(myObserver)* evaluates to *true*. This leads to the uninitialized pointer being deleted and a seg fault.

It's worth noting that if I run the release build I don't get a segfault. I only get the error in the debug build.

I was under the impression that *if(myObserver)* would only evaluate to *true* if the pointer was intact. (ie initialized and not deleted).

Comment: You're getting a segfault because of something else. `delete` **already** does a `nullptr` check. `if(ptr) delete ptr` is exactly the same as `delete ptr`.

Comment: Right: not initialized is not the same as initialized to 0. That test is never necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not initializing `myObserver` in your code so it's initial value is not knowable. You need to explicitly initialize it:

```
Observable::Observable() : myObserver(nullptr)
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Others have explained why you're getting the segmentation fault because of an uninitialized pointer, and how to fix that. You still have other bugs waiting to happen, because you're not following the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). If you make a copy of the `Observable` class both instances will now contain a copy of `myObserver`, and both will attempt to `delete` the pointer in their respective destructors, resulting in undefined behavior, and possibly a crash.

A better implementation is to follow the [rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) and not manage the pointer yourself.

```
#include <memory>

class Observable
{
public:
    Observable();
    virtual void registerObserver( std::unique_ptr<Observer> O );
    virtual ~Observable();

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Observer> myObserver;
};

Observable::Observable()
// no need to initialize pointer
{}

Observable::~Observable()
{
  // no need to delete pointer manually
}

void Observable::registerObserver( std::unique_ptr<Observer> O )
{
    myObserver.reset( O.release() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's right.  You never initialised it, so it's value is **undefined**.  That means you don't know what value it might contain because no value was ever set.  It certainly isn't guaranteed to be NULL.

You should *always* initialise your pointers.  The usual way is to do this using the initialiser-list syntax in your constructor:

```
Observable::Observable()
    : myObserver(NULL)
{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ member variables are not initialized by default.  That means your `myObserver` variable cannot be relied upon to be `0` in your example.

You need to add an initialization in your constructor to get out of the land of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
Observable::Observable() : myObserver(0)
{
}
```

`!mypointer` will evaluate to true only if `mypointer` equals 0 (`NULL`, `nullptr`, etc.) but before you explicitly set this, it's simply undefined--some random value.